# `!fontsLoaded` always true when loading custom fonts in Expo

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, fonts, expo

**I am trying to load custom fonts in my Expo app, but the !fontsLoaded condition is always true. I have checked all of the common causes for this issue, such as the fonts being in the correct format, being in the correct directory, and having a good network connection. I have also updated Expo and the expo-font package.**

Here is the code that I am using to load the fonts:

```
const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Raleway' : require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf'),
    'Playfair Display' : require('./assets/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    console.log('failed')
    return null;
  }
```

I am getting the following output:

`LOG Failed`

I have tried restarting my Expo development server, clearing my Expo cache, and uninstalling and reinstalling the expo-font package, but the issue still persists.

I would appreciate any help that you can offer in troubleshooting this issue.

Environment:

Expo SDK: 48.0.0
expo-font package: 11.0.0
Operating system: Windows 11
Device: Samsung A20s
Reproducible example:

The code that I have provided is a reproducible example of the issue.

I have attached the fonts that I am trying to load.
I have also attached the error log.

Fonts used:
Playfair Display
Raleway

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx2mA.png)]

**I am trying to load custom fonts in my Expo app, but the !fontsLoaded condition is always true. I have checked all of the common causes for this issue, such as the fonts being in the correct format, being in the correct directory, and having a good network connection. I have also updated Expo and the expo-font package.**

Here is the code that I am using to load the fonts:

```
const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Raleway' : require('./assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf'),
    'Playfair Display' : require('./assets/fonts/PlayfairDisplay-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    console.log('failed')
    return null;
  }
```

I am getting the following output:

`LOG Failed`

I have tried restarting my Expo development server, clearing my Expo cache, and uninstalling and reinstalling the expo-font package, but the issue still persists.

I would appreciate any help that you can offer in troubleshooting this issue.

Environment:

Expo SDK: 48.0.0
expo-font package: 11.0.0
Operating system: Windows 11
Device: Samsung A20s
Reproducible example:

The code that I have provided is a reproducible example of the issue.

I have attached the fonts that I am trying to load.
I have also attached the error log.

Fonts used:
Playfair Display
Raleway

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx2mA.png)]

Comment: It would be really helpful if anyone gave an answer